How to enable CSP nonce for Primefaces version 5.2
Can any one guide me how to enable CSP for primefaces version 5.2 or any older version?
I see the documentation for enabling CSP but those are for newer versions.
Can we add our custom scripts to make the primefaces scripts CSP compatible?
Looking into documentation

Just upgrade PrimeFaces itself? 5.2 is almost 10 years old!! Keep your software and libraries up to date. Always. No excuses.

We cannot upgrade immediately as lots of dependencies are there.  We tried to add nonce to script tags dynamically through JS grabbing each of the script elements and adding to that. Even after adding the nonce tags (we confirmed it was added) the CSP validation errors are coming. Any pointer or suggestion would be helpful.

I don't think CSP was available in 5.2. And no you can't just bolt CSP on.
